# Problem with codification in Jenkins console showing PHP

Tags: java, php, docker, jenkins, console

on my jenkins console output I see encoded characters on my php like & or &acirc; I have tried the JAVA_TOOLS_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 variable but still not working

Comment: What application output those characters?

Comment: Its just a job with a shell script that executes a php file, then it prints a XML from the output alredy encoding UTF-8

Comment: Can you check that php script output have proper encoding?

Comment: What do you mean? the xml output has this line on top <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> so i assume is alredy encoding it

Comment: Jenkins doesn't care about it. It doesn't process output, just show it as it is. If your php script output some broken character jenkins will not fix it. Can you add to your question example of what your script outputs and what jenkins show?

Comment: it generates the same on my xml file output generated and on my jenkins console:    <town value="B&amp;acirc;le / Basel"/> when it expects the string to contain Bâle / Basel

Comment: If your script is returning corrupted string too, then you have to fix the script. Note that `&amp` is not UTF-8 encoding. It is XML encoding.